# Disable GRUB boot manager from Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, fedora, grub

I decided to get rid of the Fedora installation on my hard drive by deleting the partitions and extending my windows partition. To repair the boot loader I used a Windows recovery disc and command prompt and ran bootrec.exe /fixmbr. My problem is that the GRUB bootloader still persists giving me the option to boot into my non-existent Fedora partition. Any ideas on removing it?

Update: Removing Fedora using EasyBCD fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that's something that you should be able to accomplish using [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (free for non-commercial use) to modify the bootloader. According to [this post](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/172382-quick-fix-removing-grub.html) looking to do a similar thing, writing a new MBR using EasyBCD worked in Windows 7, so the equivalent thing should work today.